# Is it necessary to have the same XML files in different values folders?

Tags: android

My current resource folders hierarchy looks like this:

```
res
 |__values
 |     |__analytics.xml
 |     |__dimens.xml
 |     |__strings.xml
 |     |__styles.xml
 |
 |__values-w400dp
 |     |__styles.xml
 |
 |__values-w700dp
       |__styles.xml
```

Basically, I have specialized `styles.xml` files for `w400dp` and `w700dp` screens.

My question is, do I also have to copy the rest of the files in the `values` folder (i.e. `analytics.xml`, `dimens.xml` and `strings.xml`) to my `values-w400dp` and `values-w700dp` folders?

If I don't copy them over, will Android use those files in the `values` folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the files that are in your `values` folder will be used by default. So in your case if someone uses your app with an `w700dp` device it will use:

```
 styles.xml from values-w700dp

 strings.xml from values
 analytics.xml from values
 dimens.xml from values
```

see also documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html). Feel free to test it using different devices / emulators

Comment: It should be noted that it's important that *when* you have alternate files, then *all* elements need to be reproduced. For example, if you're adding a new element to `values/dimens.xml` then **all other** `dimens.xml` files need to have this new element added as well. If not, you're going to chase your tail with the strangest crash reports ;) -- and no, it probably won't happen in development or testing, but once it's out in the wild.

Answer (score 1):

No.. It is not mandatory to keep all the files in all folders. For example if the device with 400dp needs dimens.xml which is not present in its corresponding folder, then it fallsback and tries to find the same file in default folder (ie values). If it cannot get it there, then it tries to find in similar folder (for example values-w700dp). If it cannot find it anywhere, then it shows error.